# How to enable edition in syncfusion c#

Tags: c#, excel, vba, syncfusion

I need to enable edition by default in a excel file created with syncfusion in C# using worksheets. It has macros and formulas but when somebody download this file, it opens in protected view and only calculates formulas after you enable editing and change to unprotected. ¿Is there a way to skip the protected mode warning and once you download the file you can see everything working?

Comment: No, that's not possible, for a good reason. The described behaviour is the only protection from malicious code to be executed automatically. The user could maybe set a trusted location, but that's always (for obvious reasons) done on the client side. Plus there might be policies installed that could prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the behavior of MS Excel to open the Excel files that are downloaded from the browser in protected view to ensure protection from viruses. This behavior can be disabled through options in Microsoft Excel.

​However, Syncfusion XlsIO has support for formula calculation, and we suggest you call the [Calculate](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/file-formats/Syncfusion.XlsIO.IWorksheet.html#Syncfusion_XlsIO_IWorksheet_Calculate) method of [IWorksheet](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/file-formats/Syncfusion.XlsIO.IWorksheet.html), before saving the Excel document to get the formulas calculated.